# SSO Как правильно обработать проверку был ли токен отозван ан беке?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Я собираюсь добавить функционал отзыва токена на своем Identity сервисе (написан при помощи OpenIdDict).
На сервисах бекенда, используется стандартная библиотека для работы с авторизацией (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer)

Подскажите, как правильно сконфигурировать проверку токена на беке (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) что бы автоматически выполнялась проверка [отзыва токена](https://oauth.net/2/token-revocation/) ?

Comment: Не припоминаю чтобы jwt можно было отозвать, он сам по себе не имеет состояния, и не хранится нигде кроме как у клиента. Если нужно реализовать функцию выхода, можно просто удалить токен с клиента. Конечно токен не станет недействительным сразу, но не думаю что это большая проблема, ибо токен в скором времени должен стать недействительным.